# getting wrong answer on project euler 8

Tags: c

I have tried to implement then 8th problem in C. It gives me the right answer for the consecutive 4 digit but giving wrong answer for 13. Please help me.

Here is the problem statement:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

this is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a[]={7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 9, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 9, 6, 7, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9, 1, 9, 4, 9, 3, 4, 9, 6, 9, 8, 3, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 7, 4, 5, 0, 6, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 9, 5, 7, 8, 3, 1, 8, 0, 1, 6, 9, 8, 4, 8, 0, 1, 8, 6, 9, 4, 7, 8, 8, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3, 8, 5, 8, 6, 1, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 1, 1, 2, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 5, 4, 5, 9, 5, 0, 1, 7, 3, 7, 9, 5, 8, 3, 3, 1, 9, 5, 2, 8, 5, 3, 2, 0, 8, 8, 0, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 7, 1, 5, 8, 5, 2, 3, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 1, 5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 9, 0, 9, 6, 3, 2, 9, 5, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 4, 8, 9, 5, 0, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 1, 7, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 4, 0, 3, 0, 9, 8, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 2, 2, 3, 8, 3, 1, 1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2, 9, 8, 9, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 8, 0, 3, 0, 8, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 7, 6, 6, 1, 4, 2, 8, 2, 8, 0, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 6, 4, 5, 2, 3, 8, 7, 4, 9, 3, 0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 0, 7, 2, 9, 6, 2, 9, 0, 4, 9, 1, 5, 6, 0, 4, 4, 0, 7, 7, 2, 3, 9, 0, 7, 1, 3, 8, 1, 0, 5, 1, 5, 8, 5, 9, 3, 0, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 0, 1, 7, 2, 4, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 8, 8, 3, 9, 9, 8, 7, 9, 7, 9, 0, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 4, 9, 2, 1, 9, 0, 1, 6, 9, 9, 7, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 9, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 3, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 8, 0, 9, 7, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 0, 5, 9, 4, 7, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 8, 4, 9, 0, 7, 7, 1, 1, 6, 7, 0, 5, 5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 6, 0, 4, 8, 3, 9, 5, 8, 6, 4, 4, 6, 7, 0, 6, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 3, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7, 4, 0, 6, 4, 9, 5, 5, 1, 4, 9, 2, 9, 0, 8, 6, 2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 8, 4, 6, 8, 6, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 8, 3, 9, 7, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 0, 5, 6, 0, 5, 7, 4, 9, 0, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 7, 9, 7, 2, 9, 6, 8, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5, 1, 0, 0, 4, 7, 4, 8, 2, 1, 6, 6, 3, 7, 0, 4, 8, 4, 4, 0, 3, 1, 9, 9, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 9, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 5, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 7, 5, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 1, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 4, 7, 9, 9, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 0, 8, 6, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 1, 3, 9, 1, 9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 2, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 6, 1, 7, 8, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 2, 9, 4, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2, 8, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 4, 2, 6, 0, 7, 6, 9, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 2, 6, 7, 1, 0, 5, 5, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 3, 7, 0, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 0, 6, 9, 4, 1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 6, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 7, 1, 9, 8, 4, 0, 3, 8, 5, 0, 9, 6, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 2, 9, 8, 1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 8, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9, 2, 7, 2, 4, 4, 2, 8, 4, 9, 0, 9, 1, 8, 8, 8, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 6, 0, 9, 7, 9, 1, 9, 1, 3, 3, 8, 7, 5, 4, 9, 9, 2, 0, 0, 5, 2, 4, 0, 6, 3, 6, 8, 9, 9, 1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6, 0, 6, 0, 5, 8, 8, 6, 1, 1, 6, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 4, 0, 5, 0, 7, 7, 5, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 9, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 7, 2, 5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 6, 2, 6, 9, 5, 6, 1, 8, 8, 2, 6, 7, 0, 4, 2, 8, 2, 5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 0, 0, 8, 2, 3, 2, 5, 7, 5,3,0, 4, 2, 0, 7, 5, 2, 9, 6, 3, 4, 5, 0};
    int i,j,k;
    long long int s;
    s=1;
    for(i=0;i<=987;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]*a[i+1]*a[i+2]*a[i+3]*a[i+4]*a[i+5]*a[i+6]*a[i+7]*a[i+8]*a[i+9]*a[i+10]*a[i+11]*a[i+12]>=s)
            s=a[i]*a[i+1]*a[i+2]*a[i+3]*a[i+4]*a[i+5]*a[i+6]*a[i+7]*a[i+8]*a[i+9]*a[i+10]*a[i+11]*a[i+12];
    }

    printf("%lld\n",s);
    s=1;
    for(i=0;i<=996;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]*a[i+1]*a[i+2]*a[i+3]>=s)
            s=a[i]*a[i+1]*a[i+2]*a[i+3];
    }

    printf("%lld\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: explain your question little bit more! What is your expected output? what output you are getting?

Comment: Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

Comment: question is on this link .. http://projecteuler.net/problem=8

Comment: This code makes me want to hide in a corner and cry.

Comment: replace `if ( blalbalbalblabla >= s ) s = blablalbalbal;` with `s = MAX(s, blablalbalbal);` (with `MAX` being a macro or inline function)

Comment: i dont understand that if it can check for the 4 consecutive digit why it is failing for 13!!

Comment: What do you mean by failing? Are you getting the wrong output or is it crashing???

Comment: its not crashing i am getting the output but it is the wrong output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gives the answer 2091059712 right? The correct answer is an order of magnitude greater than that.

You're bumping into integer overflow.

`a[i] * a[i+1] * ....`

is getting calculated as an `int`, which is typically only 2-4 bytes wide.
You correctly store the result as a `long int` (8 bytes in your case), but by then it's too late.

The way around this is to calculate the product step by step.

`long int product = 1;
for ( j = 0; j < 13; j++ ) product *= a[i + j];
if ( s < = product ) s = product;`

This has the added advantage of being *much* easier to read.

Comment: ... or cast each a[i+N] prior to multiplication. Nice problem seeking skills nonetheless !

Comment: You could do the cast at each point, but who wants to type that much.

Comment: Well, he was on the right track. Let's not imagine the thing with 25-length sequences.

Answer (score 1):

This will be no exhaustive answer, but directives so you can rewrite your code, because no sane person will debug that.

- Store `a` in static memory. <s>This thing is 4 megabytes, and you're dangerously close to (if not past) busting your stack.</s> This can be done by making `a` a global (put it outside of `main`), or a static local (declare it as `static int a[]`). Declaring it `const` can be a good idea too. Also, give it a meaningful name. **Edit:** evidence has proven that I don't know how to count. Still, that array has no sense being a mutable automatic variable.
- Loops will save you. Your whole `a[i]*a[i+1]*a[i+2]*a[i+3]*...*a[i+N]` is always the same term, with a counter from 0 to N. Hey, a counter, that's what a loop can do, right ?
- Format your code properly. Indentation and alignment go a long way of making a code snippet readable.

**Edit:** I tried it, and your result should be `23514624000` (23,514,624,000).

Comment: sorry for not indenting properly...And since N is upto to 13 so i directly ascessed it instead of making another loop..

Comment: That's premature optimization. Loop unrolling is the compiler's job, and it does it well, so focus on writing clear code instead.

Comment: `a` is a long way off 4 megabytes - it's less than 4kb (assuming 4 byte ints). No need to worry about stack space in this particular program.

Comment: is there any modification to my code in my system it is giving output as - 2091059712